# How to do Add and Remove input field

Tags: javascript, html, css

I created `add` input field and `remove` field. The `add` input is working fine, but `remove` item is not working. Please kindly suggest how to do this. I have attached code. Thanks in advance.

```js
var x = 1;

function addRow() {
  var e1 = document.createElement("div");
  x++;
  // e1.id = "box1";
  e1.setAttribute('id', "input_" + x);
  e1.className = "box";

  var cont = document.getElementById("content")
  cont.appendChild(e1);

  var e2 = document.createElement("input");
  e2.type = "text";
  e2.name = "name1";

  var cont1 = document.getElementById("input_" + x)
  cont1.appendChild(e2);

}

function removeElement() {
  // Removes an element from the document
  var element = document.getElementById('content');
  element.parentNode.removelastChild(element);
}
var rslt = (nodee = document.getElementById(id)).parentNode.removeChild(nodee);
```

```html
<div id="content">
</div>
<input type="button" value="add" onclick="addRow()">
<input type="button" value="Delete" onclick="removeElement()">
```

Comment: There is no `.removelastChild()` method available on [Node](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var lastEl = element.lastElementChild;
element.removeChild(lastEl);
```

Get the last element of a node using [lastElementChild](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ParentNode/lastElementChild) then remove it from parent element using [removeChild](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/removeChild)

**DEMO**

```js
var x = 1;

function addRow() {
  var e1 = document.createElement("div");
  x++;
  // e1.id = "box1";
  e1.setAttribute('id', "input_" + x);
  e1.className = "box";

  var cont = document.getElementById("content")
  cont.appendChild(e1);

  var e2 = document.createElement("input");
  e2.type = "text";
  e2.name = "name1";

  var cont1 = document.getElementById("input_" + x)
  cont1.appendChild(e2);

}

function removeElement() {
  // Removes an element from the document
  var element = document.getElementById('content');
  var lastEl = element.lastElementChild;
  element.removeChild(lastEl);
}
```

```html
<div id="content">
</div>
<input type="button" value="add" onclick="addRow()">
<input type="button" value="Delete" onclick="removeElement()">
```

Comment: Nice, Thanks lot. @Durga

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding _how_ and/or _why_ it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think `element.removelastChild` is a valid function. You may have to get the last child using

```
element.lastElementChild
```

and remove it using

```
parentnode.removeChild(childnode)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this, because 'removelastChild' is not an effective method

```
    function removeElement() {
        // Removes an element from the document
        var element = document.getElementById('content');
        var childrens = element.children;
        childrens[childrens.length-1].remove()
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

you can also try this one. This is alternate solution.

```
function removeElement() {
            var element = document.getElementById('content');
        element.removeChild(element.childNodes[0]);
```

}